# JFileChooser setCurrent directory to Homegroup or Network

Tags: java, network-programming, jfilechooser

I want that when my dialog is opened, then directly go to Homegroup. Thanks.

```
JFileChooser fc = null;
try {
    fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File(new URI("file:C:\\" + "..\\Homegroup")));
    fc.showOpenDialog(parent);
    return fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
} catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
}
```

This code is not working as I want. Thank you very much...

Comment: Please format your code properly it is really hard to read. Also give some more context to what you're doing.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a uri? Just specify the file path

Comment: Exceptions tell you what went wrong and where.  If you ignore it, how are you supposed to know what to do?  *Always* show the stack trace of a caught exception (unless you plan to make it the [cause](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#initCause-java.lang.Throwable-) of a different thrown exception).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you provide an invalid URI and thus get a URISyntaxException. Try something more clean and efficient that accesses an existing file, or learn 
URI syntax:

```
fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
```